# Change text case so that first letter of the sentence is capitalized

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Want to automatically change text case as I type on Google Sheets so that first letter of the sentence is capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

**here is a formula which can do so:**

```
=IF(EXACT(LOWER(LEFT(A2, 1)), LEFT(A2)),
 UPPER(LEFT(A2, 1))&MID(A2, 2, 999^99), A2)
```

[image: 2]

---

**otherwise, you would need some auto-correct chrome extension**